# Jackson deserialization issue with access modifier

Tags: jackson

Jackson throwing an exception in deserialization with protected access modifier.
I am trying to deserialize one object then accessing protected properties of parent class is throwing exception.

> Class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.FieldProperty can not
>   access a member  "protected"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that Jackson can see protected fields. E.g.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import static com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.PROTECTED_AND_PUBLIC;

@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = PROTECTED_AND_PUBLIC)
class Person {
    protected String name;
}
```

Or define getters and setters as needed. E.g. :

```
class Person {
    protected String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was using lombok (https://projectlombok.org) which was generating protected gettters and setters but when i do private its working fine